# Solution of non-invertible matrix equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, matrix-equations

Is the following equation solvable for positive integers $m_{1,1}$ and $m_{2,1}$?

[image]

Rephrasing the question to *A(BC)=(AB)C* form yields a diophantine equation with two unknowns $m_{1,1}$ and $m_{2,1}$. But then, I'm looking for a solution using matrix operations such as matrix inversion (if possible) which perhaps leave the unknown 2-by-1-matrix consists the unknowns $m_{1,1}$ and $m_{2,1}$ stays at the left side while the solution is at the right side. The values for the unknowns $m_{1,1}$ and $m_{2,1}$ are restricted to be positive values.

This problem is closely related to a lattice problem since $BM$ is a lattice point where $B$ is a non-singular matrix (a lattice basis) and $M$ is a integral vector. If this problem can be solved (for unique positive $m_{1,1}$ and $m_{2,1}$), then I found that it has cryptographic significance especially in lattice-based cryptography.

Comment: If you multiply out the left-hand side, you get a $1\times1$ matrix.

Comment: Note that for matrices: $A(BC)=(AB)C$.  Rephrase your question instead as $[105,132]\begin{bmatrix}m_{1,1}\\m_{2,1}\end{bmatrix}=[870]$.  One more step gives the equation $[105m_{1,1}+132m_{2,1}]=[870]$, and from there the braces can be removed.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Rephrasing the question to that form yields a diophantine equation with two unknown. As I mentioned before, I'm looking for a solution using matrix operations (if possible) which perhaps leave the unknown 2x1 matrix at the left side and the solution at the right side. The values for the unknown entries are restricted to be positive values. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Let
$$
\mathbf{A} = \left [ \begin{matrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} \\
\end{matrix} \right ], \quad
\mathbf{B} = \left [ \begin{matrix}
b_{11} & b_{12} \\ b_{21} & b_{22} \\
\end{matrix} \right ], \quad
\mathbf{M} = \left [ \begin{matrix}
m_{11} \\ m_{21} \\
\end{matrix} \right ], \quad
\mathbf{C} = \left [ \begin{matrix} c_{11} \end{matrix} \right ]
$$
so that the equation becomes
$$\mathbf{A} \mathbf{B} \mathbf{M} = \mathbf{C} \tag{1}\label{NA1}$$
which is equivalent to
$$
m_{11} ( a_{11} b_{11} + a_{12} b_{21} ) + m_{21} ( a_{11} b_{12} + a_{12} b_{22} ) = c_{11}
\tag{2}\label{NA2}
$$
Solving for $m_{21}$ yields
$$m_{21} = \frac{c_{11} - m_{11} ( a_{11} b_{11} + a_{12} b_{21} )}{a_{11} b_{12} + a_{12} b_{22}}
\tag{3}\label{NA3}
$$
Equation $\eqref{NA2}$ can be treated as a simple [Diophantine equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation)
$$a x + b y = c$$
where
$$\begin{aligned}
x &= m_{11} \\
y &= m_{21} \\
a &= a_{11} b_{11} + a_{12} b_{21} \\
b &= a_{11} b_{12} + a_{12} b_{22} \\
c &= c_{11} \\
\end{aligned} \tag{4}\label{NA4}$$

Per the [Wikipedia article on Diophantine equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation):

- There is a solution $x, y \in \mathbb{Z}$ (given $a, b, c \in \mathbb{Z}$), if and only if $c$ is a multiple of the greatest common divisor of $a$ and $b$, $d = \operatorname{GCD}(a, b)$.
- If there is a solution $x, y$, there are other solutions $x^\prime = x + k v$, $y^\prime = y - k u$, where $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, $v = b / d$, $u = a / d$.

---

If we substitute OP's values, we get
$$\begin{aligned}
a &= 105 \\
b &= 132 \\
c &= 870 \\
\end{aligned}$$
and therefore
$$\begin{aligned}
d = \operatorname{GCD}(a, b) &= 3 \\
u = \frac{a}{d} &= 35 \\
v = \frac{b}{d} &= 44 \\
\end{aligned}$$
If we look at equation $\eqref{NA3}$,
$$y = \frac{290}{44} - x \frac{35}{44}$$
we can see that for $y \ge 0$, $x \lt 58/7 \lt 9$. So, for positive $x, y$, there is a solution,
$$\left\lbrace\begin{aligned}
x = m_{11} &= 2 \\
y = m_{21} &= 5 \\
\end{aligned}\right.$$
because $y \lt 0$ for $x \ge 9$, and among the eight possible positive integer values of $x$ left, only $x = 2$ yields a positive integer $y$.

Thus, all integer solutions, not just those with positive integer $x$ and $y$, are
$$\left\lbrace\begin{aligned}
x &= 2 + 44 k \\
y &= 5 - 35 k \\
\end{aligned}\right., \quad k \in \mathbb{Z}$$

---

I do not see any sensible way to express the algorithm for finding the solutions in matrix form.

Indeed, as far as I can tell, the only way to find the first solution is via a brute force search (albeit in a very finite range).  Then again, I'm not a mathematician, and am only interested in Diophantine equations when they relate to certain lattices in molecular dynamics.

Comment: Thank you so much my friend. It helps me a lot. 2 and 5 are the desired solution for this problem. I'm still seeking for the way to solve this problem using matrix operations (since there is a way to transform a non-invertible matrix into an invertible matrix) and still doing on it. But, this really helps me a lot. thanks again..

Comment: This problem is closely related to a lattice problem since $BM$ is a lattice point where $B$ is a non-singular matrix (a lattice basis) and $M$ is a integral vector. If this problem can be solved (for unique positive $m_1$ and $m_2$), then it is useful in lattice-based cryptography.

Comment: @ArifMandangan: You're welcome! Yes, there might be a way to express the problem with only $\mathbf{M}$ on the left side; but other than $$\mathbf{M} = \mathbf{S} + k \mathbf{W}$$where $$\mathbf{S} = \left[\begin{matrix}x\\y\end{matrix}\right], \mathbf{W} = \left[\begin{matrix}v\\-u\end{matrix}\right], k\in \mathbb{Z}$$I do not have any idea how; all approaches I know about require brute force numerical testing to find $\mathbf{S}$. ($\mathbf{W}$ is known, but might be tricky to express in pure matrix form, requiring GCD() and such.)

Comment: Currently, I'm trying to solve this matrix equation $[105,132]\begin{bmatrix}m_{1,1}\\m_{2,1}\end{bmatrix}=[870] $ using pseudo inverse of the matrix $[105,132]$. Actually this is an example of the simplest case. I made it as simple as possible to seek answer from here. This problem can be generalized to higher dimension. Thanks my friend for your kind attention.